# Поиск по бд и вывод нужно строки

Tags: python, sqlite3

Добрый день.
Возникла проблема, с поиском и выводом нужной строки из базы, прошу помощи.
Есть listbox в который записываются значения  столбца. При нажатии на значение в самом лист боксе это значение записывается в m.
Нужно сделать чтобы при нажатии на значение в listbox производился поиск по таблице и выводилась вся строка. ( при нажатии на фамилию иванов выводил данные по иванову из других столбцов : логин, пароль и тд)
Конкретных примеров не нашел(( но чувствую что можно как то решить через SELECT
Заранее спасибо.

```
conn = _sqlite3.connect('bd1')
cur = conn.cursor()

okno11 = Tk()
okno11.title('текст титула')
okno11.geometry('800x600')
okno11.resizable(False, False)
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PUT")

def select_item(event):
    value = (tx.get(tx.curselection()))
    m = value[:-1]
    print(m)

textl = Label(okno11, text="пользователи:", font='Calibri')
textl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='s')
scrollbar = Scrollbar(okno11)
tx = Listbox(okno11, font=('Calibri', 12), width=20, height=15, selectmode=SINGLE, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, selectforeground='red')
scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='sn')
scrollbar.config(command=tx.yview)
tx.grid(row=1, column=0)
tx.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', select_item)

while True:
    memory = cur.fetchone()
    if memory == None:
        break
    tx.insert(END, memory[1] + "\n")

okno11.mainloop()
```

Comment: если сделать так:
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PUT WHERE FIO IN ('Иванов И.И.')
    p = cur.fetchall()
    print(p)
то возвращает строку правильно, но мне нужно чтобы вместо Иванов И.И. была переменная m . не выходит(

Answer (score 0):

как оказалось ответ близок:

```
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PUT WHERE fio like '"+ m + "%'")
```